# Extended ImageView

Tags: java, android

I want to add view extended from ImageView to layout pre-existed but there are some exceptions. My class is the following :

```
        public class BaseView extends ImageView{

        public static int X;
        public static int Y;
        public static int Length;
        public static int Weigth;
        int icon ;


        public BaseView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);
        }
        public BaseView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
            super(context, attrs, defStyle);

        }

        public BaseView(Context context, int icon, int x, int y, int l, int w) {
            super(context);
            X = x;
            Y = y;
            Length = l;
            Weigth = w;
            this.icon = icon;
        }
    }
```

The xml file :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/game_view_id">

        <com.example.younes.tourhanoi.BaseView
            android:layout_width="130dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="220dp"
            android:id="@+id/d0"
            android:background="@drawable/n5"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Please could any one help me, thank you.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? And what are the exceptions you see?

Comment: the exceptions are:                                                                                         The following classes could not be instantiated:
- com.example.younes.tourhanoi.BaseView (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
Tip: Use View.isInEditMode() in your custom views to skip code or show sample data when shown in the IDE  Exception Details java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:   com.example.younes.tourhanoi.BaseView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet)
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082)  
 ...

Comment: Your 3rd constructor in not going o call unless you call it from code . So just use predefined constructors of View class . And use a method to get extra params. Read about Creating Custom views in android .